How can I change the background color of TextField in Compose?
I want to change the background color of a TextField in Jetpack Compose, but nothing seems to work.

I have tried setting Modifier.background(color = Color.Transparent), but it does not work (color does not change).
Also, I have tried using both colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(...) and colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(...), as suggested in this question, but none of them have backgroundColor or any other parameter related to background (in Material3). I have also tried this approach, but it does not work either.

The TextField's colors are defined by the colors parameter. There are a lot of different colors that can be customized, but the ones you need are the container colors:
TextField(
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
        focusedContainerColor = Color.Green,
        unfocusedContainerColor = Color.Blue,
        disabledContainerColor = Color.Gray,
        errorContainerColor = Color.Red,
    ),
)

Set them as you like and omit those for that you want to use the default colors.
